# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I've run my program which uses selenium and gecko driver for the past week. Today I tried to turn it into a .bat file and use Windows's Task Scheduler to make it run at a specific time.
Once that time was reached(11 A.M) I got the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'
```

Here is the start of my code - specifically up to the line I got the error from:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import subprocess
import json


with open('D:\\PythonScripts\\LumiWeave\\config.json') as f:
    config = json.load(f)


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.meeba.co.il/home")
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

I tried moving the geckodriver.exe and the geckodriver.log files into the same directory as my python and bat files but it didn't help.
I would love some help, Yonatan.

Answer (score 0):

I just set the Task Scheduler to "Run with the highest privileges".